# Extracting values from Text Documents using Javascript/Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to fetch a text document using Javascript. From the text document, I need to extract all the lines that only start with ====>  . Each Line has four parts.

- ====>0012
- Some Texts - sometime with space, sometime without space also sometime with special characters.
- A nine digit number or empty space (102020900)
- Amount. Sometime Amount is just an empty space.

I need those four parts into arrays.

With my code, I can extract the first part successfully. But, I am finding it difficult to extract the other parts the way I wanted.

[Here is my text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hi_Wb9j_Avx-muHGphx7Tsdz1SVWNLxp/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code:

```
document.querySelector('#textdata').addEventListener('click', getTexts);

async function getTexts() {
  const response = await fetch('example.txt');
  const textData = await response.text();

  // First Part
  const re = /====>\d+/gim;
  const serial = textData.match(re);

  for (let i = 0; i < serial.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('.one').innerHTML += `${serial[i]}<br>`;
  }

  // Second Part
  const me = /([a-zA-Z\s.\-\/]{1,30})/gim;
  const descr = textData.match(me);

  for (let k = 0; k < descr.length; k++) {
    document.querySelector('.two').innerHTML += `${descr[k]}<br>`;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if regex is the best way to do it. But, I tried with regex. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: But your 9 digit number is not present in `SBTL 5 : Short Term Borwngs` although the same line has a balance... can you explain that one case? Or I'm just as confused as you are?

Comment: Yes, sometime that part comes with empty space.Anyway, probably we can make every characters into arrays. Then, first part should contain 10 characters then a space, then second part contains 30 characters (with spaces), third part contains 9 characters and then there are spaces for 41 characters and then numbers? Can we do that?

Comment: The easiest thing to start with is getting rows by splitting line breaks  returning an array. From there it would be an easy filter to get rows starting with the `===>`.Since I suck at regex I would then consider trying using character counts in what appear to be well structured (consistent length) columns

Comment: Or, can we just put each line into arrays and then slice them? But, each line must start with ====>  first part should contain 10 characters then a space, then second part contains 30 characters (with spaces), third part contains 9 characters and then there are spaces for 41 characters and then numbers? Can we do that?

Comment: @charlietfl Yours is a good idea. How do I make each line into arrays? The lines must start with ====>

Comment: simplest form is `let arr = text.split('\n').filter(s=> s.trim().startsWith('====>'))`. You can easily find  more robust regex with `\r` in it also.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your help. I've posted an answer which works perfectly for me. Your idea helped me find a solution. I highly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting problem, glad it's not mine though!

Answer (score 0):

To get only the lines having those 4 pairs you could use:

```
/^====>(\d+) (.+)(\d{9}) +(\d*.\d{2})$/mg
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/4LANVd/1) and Example:

```js
const str = `Jump to:   REPORT.LIST >
Results 1 - 1 of 1  
Refresh Selection Screen    Toggle Timer
    Enquiry Actions     Report :19177070242239900 - VIEW &HOLD&>19177070242239900 : BD0012515
    











  RE000010 NOWABPUR COR.DHAKA2515      STATEMENT OF AFFAIRS(Geneal Ledger) AS AT CLOSE OF 30 JUN 2020                   PAGE NO    1
  AREA NAME Central Bank                                                                             PRINTED AT 06:13 ON 02 JUL 2020
        TO: Treasury Secretary                    CentralBnk  ( IN FULL AMOUNT )                                                    

LINE      DESCRIPTION                   LEGACY GL CODE                         CLOSING BALANCE
------    -----------------             ---------------                        ---------------

====>     LIABLITY & EQUITY                                 
====>0012 ==============================                    
====>0014 ==============================                    
====>0016 Liabilities                                       
====>0018 Borrow. other BanksFin.instt. 101000000           
====>0020 Short Term Borrwowings                            
====>0022 ------------------------------                    
====>0024  T.T.Sold                     101010000                                         0.00
====>0030 SBTL 5 : Short Term Borwngs                                                     0.00
====>0032 L.T.Borrow.fromB.B.Counter Fin101020000           
====>0034 ------------------------------                    
====>0036 Rural Housing Scheme-         101020100                                         40.00
====>0038 Borrowing from ADB-           101020200                                         90.00
====>0040 IFAD Loan                     101020300                                         100.00
====>0042 ISLAMI BANKING UNIT           101020400                                         45.50
====>0044 O/L PAYABLE TO SME            101020500                                         0.00
====>0045 Refinance for Rural Credit    101020510                                         0.00
====>0046 Borrowing from EGBMP          101020600                                         15.75
====>0047 Refinance for COVID-19(Salary)101020900                                         0.00
====>0048 Borr.frm.BB-BaknaBasur Refin.F101020700                                         0.00
====>0049 Borrow.from.BB-Jute Refin.Fin 101020800                                         0.00
====>0050 SBTL 5:L.T.Borw. B.B.Contr Fin                                                  0.00

====>0052  Agrani Bank Shlp Unayan Bnd                      
====>0054 ------------------------------                    
====>0056 Agrani Bank Shilpa U.Bnd      101030000                                         0.00
====>0057 Agrani Bank 1st Subordi.Bond  101031000                                         0.00
====>0066 SBTL 5:Agrani Bank ShilpaUBond                                                  0.00
`;

const regex = /^====>(\d+) (.+)(\d{9}) +(\d*.\d{2})$/mg;
let m;
while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
  const [_, line, desc, code, bal] = m;
  console.log(line, desc, code, bal);
}
```

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the heads up! This regex is far from perfect. It does only match lines with exactly those 4 pairs (ignoring the ones missing) but hopefully will give OP a *good-to-go*

Comment: Curious myself what they want to do with those other lines. Still wondering if this could be done with some simple substring indexing once the rows are filtered

Comment: Hey, I've got a solution and posted an answer. Thanks @charlietfl for your ideas. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer. The following code works for me.

```
document.querySelector('#textdata').addEventListener('click', getTexts);

async function getTexts() {
  const response = await fetch('example.txt');
  const textData = await response.text();

  // First Part
  const re = /(^====).+/gim;
  const serial = textData.match(re);
  console.log(serial);

  for (let i = 0; i < serial.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('.one').innerHTML += `${serial[i].slice(0, 10)}<br>`;
  }

  // Second Part
  const me = /(^====).+/gim;

  const descr = textData.match(me);

  for (let k = 0; k < descr.length; k++) {
    document.querySelector('.two').innerHTML += `${descr[k].slice(10, 40)}<br>`;
  }

  // Third Part
  const ne = /(^====).+/gim;

  const glcode = textData.match(me);

  for (let l = 0; l < glcode.length; l++) {
    document.querySelector('.three').innerHTML += `${glcode[l].slice(
      40,
      49
    )}<br>`;
  }

  // Fourth Part
  const se = /(^====).+/gim;

  const amount = textData.match(se);

  for (let x = 0; x < amount.length; x++) {
    document.querySelector('.four').innerHTML += `${amount[x].slice(
      60,
      95
    )}<br>`;
  }
}
```